# Dynamic Page Margins CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a website in which I want to have a similar layout as Stackoverflow regarding browser window resize.

So I have the following CSS :

```
#site-container {
    margin: 0px auto;
    text-align: left;
    width: 100%;
    zoom: 1;
    position: relative;
}

body {
    font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 81.25%;
    background-color: #fbf9ef;
}

#div-menu {
    display: inline;
}

#header {
    width: 990px;
    height: 80px;
    margin-left : 127px;
    margin-right : 127px;
    margin-bottom: 12px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #c0c0c0;
}

#content {
    width: 990px;
    margin-left : 127px;
    margin-right : 127px;
}
```

However when I resize my browser Window it does not behave like Stackoverflow, somehow Stackoverflow seems to be Floating and automatically reduce margins according to the browser window size.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `margin-left: auto; margin-right: 0` to make block element to center, not fixed margin values.

Comment: But Stackoverflow also have a margin on the right. Putting margin 0 on the right the containers stay glued to the browser window.

Comment: Another possibility is to put margin right and left auto, and put a fixed padding to the left and right also.

Comment: I didn't say to set `margin: 0`, I said `margin-left / margin-right: auto;`. This is the most common and conventional way to do that. No need to use padding

Answer (score 3):

**Step 1**

Set your `#site-container` element's width to a fixed value (e.g. `990px`), rather than to `100%`. Currently, it automatically fills the window, leaving no room for any margin. StackOverflow uses a fixed value of `980px`. I believe your site uses `990px`.

Alternatively, you can set your container to have table-like layout with `display:table;`. This way it will stretch dynamically according to the width of its content. In this case, there's no need for any `width` declaration.

**Step 2**

Remove the fixed margins from your `#header` and `#content` elements. They are redundant and distort the position of the whole layout. The parent `#site-container` will have enough margin for them both.